# Display left Textview according the right one If the line fills the gap between the first textview and second should maximize automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, textview

[what it is Displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ3gE.jpg)
what I want to display if my data is entered it automatically margin or set  to the data [what I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCzmD.jpg)

help me as soon as possible

> I am fetching the data from the database and I want to display the text and the data automatically margin to the the database text

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1.0" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large sad   jhghjgh ghvfh jhgjhg jhg hghg hghjgh hg                                                              Text"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Medium Text       hdghfhgvjh                                                                  ds           fdhgcghgf     fghhvh      f"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text      hgfdgf hgfhgfh                                                        f    gfdgfdgf f"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your questions is confusing. What is it that you are trying to achieve? and what is happening now

Comment: look the image bro what i want to display  and want I wanted to display

Comment: you want to remove space between two words ??

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large Text"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewq"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large sad   jhghjgh ghvfh jhgjhg jhg hghg hghjgh hg                                                              Text" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewa"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Medium Text       hdghfhgvjh                                                                  ds           fdhgcghgf     fghhvh      f" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewe"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text      hgfdgf hgfhgfh                                                        f    gfdgfdgf f" />
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @sarvesh if it help then you can tick mark. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code it suites to your requirement

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large Text"

            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewq"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Large sad                                jhghjgh ghvfh jhgjhg jhg hghg hghjgh hg                                                              Text"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewa"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text       hdghfhgvjh                                                                  ds           fdhgcghgf     fghhvh      f"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewe"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text      hgfdgf hgfhgfh                                                        f    gfdgfdgf f"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put two Textview in LinearLayout. and than set Linearlayout gravity center like these :

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

do same for three linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use this portion code as your basic Layout structure. It will keep each your item in a perfectly Horizontal Alignment.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Text on Right"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Text on Left"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

However, I would suggest you to use RecyclerView. [Check this link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView).
You will just need one xml layout and you will add it as your ITEM to your parent layout. So, does not matter if you have 50, 60, 70 or 3 items in your DB, your layout will recycle itself AUTOMATICALLY. no hassle.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

EDITED:
the layout code I have given should be inside a linearLayout which has to be VERTICAL.